# Site indexing by Google (Google Webmaster Tools)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search-engine

In brief: my site is not being indexed by Google. Google has a lot of docs in their FAQ but they do not tell how long it takes until a site is indexed: hours? days? weeks? (the latter would be an explaination, the site is online for just a week).

What I did until now:

- registered with Google Webmastertools and validated both without and with www.
- put my site's atom feed to sitemaps in the Webmastertools and provided a basic textfile with 5 basic urls of the site (main, contact, about, ...) --> show 19 urls, 0 indexed.
- robots.txt set to all  (last fetched by google 4 hours ago) [User-agent: *  Allow: / ]
- Webmastertools "fetch as google bot" tested ok

The site is a Rails site and pretty accessible. It consists mostly of articles so there should not be any problem to fetch it for google (http://www.communityguides.eu). 
Clearly there are no sites with high pagerank linking to it, however, my question is about indexing at all. Did I forget something or do I just have to be patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely more weeks than days. Keep patient, it might take several week for a first index!